Create QML grouped properties in PyQt6
I am trying to replicate this PySide6 example to PyQt6. The example creates a grouped property ShoeDescription in Python and exposes it to Qml. Here are the relevant files:
person.py
from PyQt6.QtCore import QObject, pyqtProperty, pyqtSignal
from PyQt6.QtGui import QColor


class ShoeDescription(QObject):
    
    brand_changed = pyqtSignal()
    size_changed = pyqtSignal()
    price_changed = pyqtSignal()
    color_changed = pyqtSignal()
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._brand = ''
        self._size = 0
        self._price = 0
        self._color = QColor()
        
    @pyqtProperty(str, notify=brand_changed, final=True)
    def brand(self):
        return self._brand
    
    @brand.setter
    def brand(self, b):
        if self._brand != b:
            self._brand = b
            self.brand_changed.emit()
            
    @pyqtProperty(int, notify=size_changed, final=True)
    def size(self):
        return self._size
    
    @size.setter
    def size(self, s):
        if self._size != s:
            self._size = s
            self.size_changed.emit()
            
    @pyqtProperty(float, notify=price_changed, final=True)
    def price(self):
        return self._price
    
    @price.setter
    def price(self, p):
        if self._price != p:
            self._price = p
            self.price_changed.emit()
            
    @pyqtProperty(QColor, notify=color_changed, final=True)
    def color(self):
        return self._color
    
    @color.setter
    def color(self, c):
        if self._color != c:
            self._color = c
            self.color_changed.emit()


class Person(QObject):
    
    name_changed = pyqtSignal()
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._name = ''
        self._shoe = ShoeDescription()
        
    @pyqtProperty(str, notify=name_changed, final=True)
    def name(self):
        return self._name
    
    @name.setter
    def name(self, n):
        if self._name != n:
            self._name = n
            self.name_changed.emit()
        
    @pyqtProperty(ShoeDescription)
    def shoe(self):
        return self._shoe


class Boy(Person):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        
class Girl(Person):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

birthdayparty.py
from PyQt6.QtCore import QObject, pyqtProperty, pyqtSignal, pyqtClassInfo
from PyQt6.QtQml import QQmlListProperty

from person import Person

@pyqtClassInfo('DefaultProperty', 'guests')
class BirthdayParty(QObject):
    
    host_changed = pyqtSignal()
    guests_changed = pyqtSignal()
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._host = None
        self._guests = []
        
    @pyqtProperty(Person, notify=host_changed, final=True)
    def host(self):
        return self._host
    
    @host.setter
    def host(self, h):
        if self._host != h:
            self._host = h
            self.host_changed.emit()
            
    def guest(self, n):
        return self._guests[n]
    
    def guestCount(self):
        return len(self._guests)
    
    def appendGuest(self, guest):
        self._guests.append(guest)
        self.guests_changed.emit()
        
    @pyqtProperty(QQmlListProperty)
    def guests(self):
        return QQmlListProperty(Person, self, self._guests)

main.py
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PyQt6.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from PyQt6.QtQml import QQmlComponent, QQmlEngine, qmlRegisterType, qmlRegisterAnonymousType

from person import Boy, Girl, Person, ShoeDescription
from birthdayparty import BirthdayParty


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    
    qmlRegisterType(Boy, 'People', 1, 0, 'Boy')
    qmlRegisterType(Girl, 'People', 1, 0, 'Girl')
    qmlRegisterType(BirthdayParty, 'People', 1, 0, 'BirthdayParty')
    qmlRegisterAnonymousType(Person, 'People', 1)
    qmlRegisterAnonymousType(ShoeDescription, 'People', 1)
    
    engine = QQmlEngine()
    engine.addImportPath(str(Path(__file__).parent))

    component = QQmlComponent(engine)
    component.loadFromModule('People', 'Main')
    
    party = component.create()
    
    if not party:
        for e in component.errors():
            print(e.toString())
            
    host = party.host
    print("Host name: ", host.name)
    
    print("Guests:")
    for guest in party.guests:
        print("\t" + guest.name)

People/Main.qml
import QtQuick
import People


BirthdayParty {
    host: Boy {
        name: "Bob Jones"
        shoe { size: 12; color: "white"; brand: "Bikey"; price: 90.0 }
    }

    Boy {
        name: "Leo Hodges"
        shoe { size: 10; color: "black"; brand: "Thebok"; price: 59.95 }
    }
    Boy { name: "Jack Smith"
        shoe {
            size: 8
            color: "blue"
            brand: "Luma"
            price: 19.95
        }
    }
    Girl {
        name: "Anne Brown"
        shoe.size: 7
        shoe.color: "red"
        shoe.brand: "Job Macobs"
        shoe.price: 699.99
    }
}

Main/qmldir
module People
typeinfo coercion.qmltypes
Main 1.0 Main.qml

This the error I get when I run main.py
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
file:......./005/People/Main.qml:8:9: Invalid grouped property access: Property "shoe" with type "", which is neither a value nor an object type
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "................\005\main.py", line 33, in <module>
    host = party.host
           ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'host'

I am useng qmlRegisterType and qmlRegisterAnonymousType to register Python classes with Qml but I can not figure out how to expose my ShoeDescription which "Property "shoe" with type "", which is neither a value nor an object type" seems to indicate.

It appears that the order of qmlRegisterType() calls matters. First had to call it for ShoeDescription, then for Person, then for Boy and Gil and finally for BirthdayParty. Also all registrations were used using qmlRegisterType() not qmlRegisterAnonymousType(). The code for this example is actually available in the PyQt6 source distribution which I downloaded from PyPI in examples/qml/referenceexamples/grouped.py as a single file that contains both the QML and Python classes.
Here is main.py that works:
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PyQt6.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from PyQt6.QtQml import QQmlComponent, QQmlEngine, qmlRegisterType

from person import Boy, Girl, Person, ShoeDescription
from birthdayparty import BirthdayParty
from PyQt6.QtGui import QColor


def guest_change_handler():
    print("\nGuests changed!\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    qmlRegisterType(ShoeDescription, 'People', 1, 0)
    qmlRegisterType(Person, 'People', 1, 0)    
    qmlRegisterType(Boy, 'People', 1, 0)
    qmlRegisterType(Girl, 'People', 1, 0)
    qmlRegisterType(BirthdayParty, 'People', 1, 0)
    """
    qmlRegisterType(Boy, 'People', 1, 0)
    qmlRegisterType(Girl, 'People', 1, 0)
    qmlRegisterType(BirthdayParty, 'People', 1, 0)
    qmlRegisterType(Person, 'People', 1, 0)
    qmlRegisterType(ShoeDescription, 'People', 1, 0)
    """
    engine = QQmlEngine()
    engine.addImportPath(str(Path(__file__).parent))

    component = QQmlComponent(engine)
    component.loadFromModule('People', 'Main')
    
    party = component.create()
    
    if not party:
        for e in component.errors():
            print(e.toString())
            
    host = party.host
    print("Host name: ", host.name)
    
    print("Guests:")
    for guest in party.guests:
        print("\t" + guest.name)
    
    party.guests_changed.connect(guest_change_handler)
    
    me = Boy()
    me.name = 'Me, Myself and I'
    my_shoes = ShoeDescription()
    my_shoes.brand = "Some brand"
    my_shoes.price = 123.45
    my_shoes.size = 12
    my_shoes.color = QColor("Black") 
    me.shoe = my_shoes
    
    party.appendGuest(me)
    
    print("Guests:")
    for guest in party.guests:
        print("\t" + guest.name)

I also added a setter for shoes in the Person class:
@shoe.setter
def shoe(self, value):
    self._shoe = value

so I could test adding a new guest to the party.
